Node project with mongodb never loads on specific routes
I have been making a small API for practicing purposes, but I'm encountering problems getting data for my Mongodb database collection, when I open a specific route the controller looks like that doesn't send anything, and the API keeps loading forever with any response
The database connect when I start the node project it gives me a message that it connects however when I try a route like /authors it nevers gives me an answer not even an error so I can't figure out what is going on and it keeps loading forever with no answer at all, I have made a similar API like this for learning purposes and it works perfectly I don't know what is going on with this one. My environment variable has the name of the collection in the URI
here's my code
server.js
    const express = require('express');
    const mongodb = require('./db/connect');
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use('/', require('./routes'));

    process.on('uncaughtException', (err, origin) => {
      console.log(
        process.stderr.fd,
        `Caught exception: ${err}\n` + `Exception origin: ${origin}`
      );
    });

    mongodb.initDb((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('The database connection failed');
      } else {
        app.listen(port);
        console.log(`Connected to DB and listening on ${port}`);
      }
    });

    db connect.js
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    dotenv.config();
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    let _db;

    const initDb = (callback) => {
      if (_db) {
        console.log('Db is already initialized!');
        return callback(null, _db);
      }
      MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
        .then((client) => {
          _db = client;
          callback(null, _db);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          callback(err);
        });
    };


    const getDb = () => {
      if (!_db) {
        throw Error('Db not initialized');
      }
      return _db;
    };

    module.exports = {
      initDb,
      getDb,
    };


routes index.js
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Running');
    });

    router.use('/authors', require('./authors'));

    module.exports = router;

routes authors.js
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const authorsController = require('../controllers/authorsController');

    router.get('/', authorsController.getAll);
    /*router.get('/:id', authorsController.getAuthorById);
    router.get('/:id/books', authorsController.getAuthorBooks);
    router.post('/', authorsController.addNewAuthor);
    router.put('/:id', authorsController.updateAuthorInfo);
    router.delete('/:id', authorsController.deleteAuthor);*/

    module.exports = router;

controllers authorsController
    const mongodb = require('../db/connect');
    const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

    const getAll = async (req, res) => {
      const result = await mongodb.getDb().db().collection('authors').find();
      result.toArray((err, lists) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).json({ message: err });
        }
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.status(200).json(lists);
      });
    };

    const getAuthorById = async (req, res) => {
      if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
        res.status(400).json('Author ID is not valid');
      }
      const userId = req.params.id;
      const result = await mongodb
        .getDb()
        .db()
        .collection('authors')
        .find({ _id: userId });
      result.toArray((err, lists) => {
        if (condition) {
          res.status(400).json({ message: err });
        }
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.status(200).json(lists);
      });
    };



    module.exports = {
      getAll,
      getAuthorById,
    };

these are my package json dependencies
        "body-parser": "^1.20.3",
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "express": "^4.21.1",
        "mongodb": "^6.9.0",
        "nodemon": "^3.1.7"
      }


Please format you code properly and dont put file names inside code blocks.



if, router file is different, did you use that router file in main index.js file?


without using controller, direct use function in route and console.log there if router working perfectly.


in some error you just send response, so you should return the response when checking error and want to send response


use this to check in console that your specific route is hitting or not!


// Middleware to log route information
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Route hit: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
    next(); 
});```

Yes I used that router file in main index, also I checked if the router works with a function as you said and it gave me an answer, I used the function you told me to use as middleware and it hit the route that I wanted: Route hit: GET /authors.  below I'll share my MongoDB string to connect with my cluster and database                         mongodb+srv://(here-should-go-my-username-and -password)@cluster0.ehu0c.mongodb.net/week2_3_activity

I added a return with a console log in my controller's first function in if statement to check for an error, but neither gives me an answer.
